# Scroll down in popup window using selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just started using selenium library in excel VBA.
I am trying to print the followers on Instagram to Excel, but the window that shows the people I'm following doesn't show the contacts unless they go down.

I've tried:

```
driver.ExecuteScript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"
```

but it didn't work.
I've tried `.ScrollIntoView`, but it didn't work too.

My code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim baglan As New Selenium.WebDriver, el As WebElements

baglan.AddArgument ("--incognito")
baglan.Start "chrome"

baglan.Get ("instagram.com/")
baglan.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input").SendKeys "username"
baglan.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input").SendKeys "password"
baglan.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button/div").Click
baglan.Wait 10000
baglan.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]").Click


baglan.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/a").Click
baglan.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a").Click
a = baglan.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/span").Text
baglan.ExecuteScript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);" 
Set el = baglan.FindElementByClass("PZuss").FindElementsByTag("li")

For i = 1 To a
baglan.Wait 1000

'Cells(i, 1) = baglan.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[" & i & "]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a").Text
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Describe what is meant by doesn't work. Sometimes pages have frames with their own scroll bars and scrolling window height will not affect these.

Comment: when I click on the people I am following, a new window appears and this window does not load all the information.the page needs to go down to the bottom to load all the information @QHarr

Comment: Is your request similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681446/scroll-down-followers-following-list-in-the-instagram-box

Comment: this is exactly what i want but i couldn't do it in vba

Comment: did you try executing the same string with baglan.ExecuteScript but verifying the css selectors within the string?

Comment: I've been dealing for about 2 hours. I think I'm having a hard time because I don't know other languages. I guess I couldn't fully understand the codes in the example and adapt them to vba.

Comment: baglan.ExecuteScript will execute the javascript string passed to it. In the python example the javascript is targeting a node by css. document.querySelector('div[role="dialog"] .isgrP' and scrolling that. The selector part is _div[role="dialog"] .isgrP_.  which is a node with class . isgrP_ which is a child of a parent _div_ with _role_ attribute having value _dialog_. The space between is a descendant combinator. You need to check in the browser elements tab if this selector is correct in your case. Read about css selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your answers. I will improve myself by trying and researching new things. thanks again.